# c++11: Why a in-class initialization of a static constexpr not a definition?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the simple following:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class Test {
public:
    static constexpr int a = 1;
}

#endif
```

Note:

1. There's no ODR violation due to the macro.
2. Why the constexpr static int a not considered a definition since it's defined in the class Test? Because it's not a definition, hence it needs the below outside of the class. Why?

> constexpr int Test::a;

Comment: This is not required again since C++17.

Comment: Before inline variables, all static member variables had to be defined in a single TU, to avoid breaking ODR.  C++17 introduced inline variables, which makes this problem go away.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145299 for a detailed explanation.

Comment: *"There's no ODR violation due to the macro."* - Include guards don't protect from ODR violations. They protect a single TU from re-inclusion, but the ODR applies across the *entire program* and all of its TUs!

Comment: See my question to Jerry below. Tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why a in-class initialization of a static constexpr not a definition?

Because of One Definition Rule (ODR). The rule says that there must be exactly one definition of each non-inline non-member and static member variable. Class definitions, due to their nature, are typically included into multiple translation units. If class definition contained a variable definition, then inclusion into multiple translation units would violate the ODR.

Since C++17, the language has inline variables, so you can define such inline variables within class definitions.

Comment: I understand ODR but here's my question. Why would the above  constexpr static data member a violate ODR if we have macro #define in that file itself as above? Thought multiple files might include this class .. there will always be 1 class definition of Test.

Comment: @yapkm01  If you compile `g++ -c a.cpp; g++ -c b.cpp; g++ a.o b.o` and both a.cpp and b.cpp include your header the include guard does not prevent the class definition from appearing in the executable twice because each cpp file is compiled separately and so each has to include the class..

Comment: if a.cpp and b.cpp both contains header which has class Test and as you said the header guard is for each TU, how linking them will satisfy ODR since both a.o & b.o both contains class Test?

Comment: @yapkm01 Because ODR allows classes to be defined in each TU provided that the definition is identical.

Comment: Why same classes are allowed across TUs if they are considered as definition. Like int a = 1; definition must not be duplicate across TUs? Unless you're saying no storage is involved at this stage (?) What about constexpr static member in classes? Aren't they considered to be definition? Looks like not since compiler just use them to replace where's needed (?)

Comment: @yapkm01 `Why same classes are allowed...` Because the language spec says so. `Like int a = 1; definition must not be duplicate across TUs?` It must not. `What about constexpr static member ... Aren't they considered to be definition?` No. It is a declaration.

Comment: Why is constexpr static int = 1; considered declaration when there's a value assigned?

Comment: @yapkm01 Because it's in a class definition.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing. We have class definition which is allowed across TUs. When we talk about definition it's also assumed there's storage involved like int a=1; Seems like class definition does not have storage. Why? Because e.g. constexpr int y=2; is not a definition but a declaration in a class definition. There's no storage here .. so it seems. This is mind boggling.

Comment: @yapkm01 `When we talk about definition it's also assumed there's storage involved` No. "Definition" is a language concept. Classes and functions have definitions which have nothing to do with "storage". Objects have storage. `Seems like class definition does not have storage. Why?` Why would a class definition have storage?

Comment: Ok. Got it! Appreciate for your patience :O)